# Is there any way to hook insertion and deletion operations for the std containers?

Tags: c++, containers, std

Let's say, we are going to subclass the `std::map` and we need to catch all insertions and deletions to/from the container. For example, in order to save some application-specific information about the keys present in the container.

What's the easiest way to do this, if at all possible?

Probably, the most obvious way to do this is to override all methods and operators that perform the insertion and deletion. But I think, something may be easily lost sight of on this way, isn't it?

Comment: You could use composition and provide proxy functions to access the map. That way you don't have to implement more proxy functions than what's currently needed.

Comment: You could provide your own allocator that tracks allocation, construction, destruction and deallocation.

Comment: Even if you replace all functions, the user can still (a) cast to reference to `std::map` can call the original functions, and (b) do `obj->map::some_func()` to call the original function.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I actually thought about providing an own memory allocator. But, whether calls to it will be only on insertion and deletion? I am confused by that it may be called to perform some internal operation (elements' relocation, for example). As far as I know, there is no such a guarantee somewhere in the documentation.

Comment: @SergeRoussak `std::map` never relocates elements. That is guaranteed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do that in the general case. Inheritance is not a good idea because `std::map` is not polymorphic and no virtual dispatch will happen when you use a pointer to a map. You might as well use a simple wrapper class at that point and save yourself a lot of hassle:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template <class Key, class Value> 
struct Map {
private:
  std::map<Key, Value> _data;

public:
  template <class Y, class T> 
  void insert(Y &&key, T &&val) {

    std::cout << "[" << key << "] = " << val << "\n";

    _data.insert_or_assign(std::forward<Y>(key), std::forward<T>(val));
  }

  void remove(Key const &key) {
    auto const it = _data.find(key);

    if (it == _data.end())
      return;

    std::cout << "[" << key << "] -> removed\n";

    _data.erase(it);
  }

  Value *get(Key const &key) {
    auto const it = _data.find(key);

    if (it == _data.end())
      return nullptr;

    return &it->second;
  }
};

int main() {
  Map<int, char const *> map;
  map.insert(10, "hello");
  map.insert(1, "world");
  map.remove(1);
  map.remove(10);
  map.remove(999);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **No**

C++ standard library data structures were not designed to support this use case. You may subclass and try to override but this will not work as you'd expect. In fact you'll get an error at compile time if you do it properly with the help of the keyword `override`. The problem is that `std::map` methods are not `virtual` so they don't support so called *late binding*. Functions that work with references and pointers to `std::map` will keep using `std::map` methods even in the case of passing instances of your `std::map` subclass.

Your only option is to create a completely new class `your_map` with a subset of requred methods of `std::map` and to delegate the job to an inner instance of `std::map` as shown in Ayxan Haqverdili's answer. Unfortunately this solution requires you to change the signature of functions working with your code replacing `std::map &` arguments with `your_map &` which may not be always possible.